# Expression Tree $a \times (b \times (c \times (d \times e + f) - g) + h) + j$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am learning expression trees and understand the basics, but am having troubles when it comes to parenthesis.

Here is the question:

$$a \times (b \times (c \times (d \times e + f) - g) + h) + j$$

Where do I begin?  What is considered the root tree?

Any help or tutorials will definitely help out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s use parentheses of different sizes to make the structure a little more obvious:

$$a\times\bigg(b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\bigg)+j\tag{1}$$

If you had values for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$, and $j$, what is the last calculation that you would make in evaluating $(1)$? Everything inside the parentheses has to be done before you can do either the multiplication by $a$ or the addition of $j$, and multiplication is done before addition, so the last operation is the addition of $$a\times\bigg(b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\bigg)$$ and $j$. The root of your tree is therefore that addition:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
&&+\\
&\swarrow&&\searrow\\
a\times\bigg(b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\bigg)&&&&j
\end{array}\tag{2}$$

Now repeat the process with the lefthand leaf of $(2)$. The last operation that you would perform in evaluating that expression is the multiplication by $a$, so it becomes the root of the left subtree: you replace the node

$$a\times\bigg(b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\bigg)$$ by

$$\begin{array}{}
&&\times\\
&\swarrow&&\searrow\\
a&&&&b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\\
\end{array}$$

Continue in the same way; at east stage the **last** operation that would be performed in an actual calculation becomes the root of the next subtree. When you’re all done, you should get the tree below:

```
                                              +  
                                             / \  
                                            x   j  
                                           / \  
                                          a   +  
                                             / \  
                                            x   h  
                                           / \  
                                          b   -  
                                             / \  
                                            x   g  
                                           / \  
                                          c   +  
                                             / \  
                                            x   f  
                                           / \  
                                          d   e
```

To reverse the process, you’d work from the bottom up. The only operation node that can be evaluated immediately is the one that yields $d\times e$. Once you have that, you can add $f$ to get $d\times e+f$. Then you can premultiply by $c$ to get $c\times(d\times e+f)$, subtract $g$ to get $$c\times(d\times e+f)-g\;,$$ premultiply by $b$ to get $$b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)\;,$$ add $h$ to get $$b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\;,$$ premultiply by $a$ to get $$a\times\bigg(b\times\Big(c\times(d\times e+f)-g\Big)+h\bigg)\;,$$ and finally add $j$ to get the original expression, $(1)$.

Comment: That typesetting must have been tedious. +1

Comment: Wow!  That's some thorough explanation!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @tray: You’re very welcome.